# react-tool's JSX compile a not generating JS script

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to convert a React.js script using the JSX syntax into a script in plain js syntax
I used react-tool like recommanded in http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx

But the output file simply doesnt work : no error in the browser console, nothing

The script (with the JSX syntax) can be found at :
http://www.youni.education/javascripts/postslist.js

And you can see it working just fine at: http://www.youni.education/universities/University_of_Warwick

Comment: Since there is no error, I am at a loss where to start debugging

Comment: Why are there no semicolons in your file?

Comment: in javascript semicolons are optionals in most cases.

Comment: What file are you talking about? there are a lot of semicolons in the file I linked.

Comment: I created a jsFiddle from your js file and there are errors in the console log: http://jsfiddle.net/vgbhs5nf/. Also in your case are you sure your component is mounted? Do you have an element with id `loadposts` in your html?

Comment: hi nilgun, thx for your help. The script is working (indeed it mounts on the loadposts element), you can see it working in the page I linked.
The errors in the jsfiddle come from the lack of a few html element in the html code of the fiddle.

Comment: My question is not about the script itself which is working, but the output of React-tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. If the extension of your file is jsx use `--extension jsx`
2. I've read that the `jsx` tool fails silently if you give it the wrong src and dest dirs