# JSX compiler output is not valid JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm playing with React and I've run into a problem with the offline JSX compiler.

Here's my JSX code in a file named **helloworld.js**, placed in a folder named **src** within the root directory of my project:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <div>
                <h3>Hello, {this.props.name}</h3>
            </div>
    }
});

React.renderComponent(
    <Hello name={"Jane Doe"} />,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

In the command line, when I navigate to the root directory of my project and  I run this:

```
jsx /src /build
```

The output file **helloworld.js** is produced in the **build** folder but it does not contain valid JavaScript.

Here's how the content looks like:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Hello = React.createClass({displayName: "Hello",
    render: function () {
        return <div>
                <h3>Hello, {this.props.name}</h3>
            </div>
    }
});

React.renderComponent(
    <Hello name={"Jane Doe"} />,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

As you can see, it still contains the inline HTML instead of valid JavaScript.
There is no indication of an error in the command line. It looks like this:

```
built Module("helloworld")
["helloworld"]
```

Does anyone have an idea why that might be happening?

Comment: try to do `jsx --watch -x jsx src/ build/`

Comment: also you should do `React.render(....);` instead of `React.renderComponent();`

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these suggestions worked. 
I would also imagine that the JSX compiler is not aware of the React API but simply renders the inline HTML into proper JavaScript.

Comment: works for me, so try `npm install -g react-tools` and try again, also what version of react are you using?

Comment: I installed react-tools before. Are you asking about the version of react-tools or React (I's say it's irrelevant as I'm not linking it anywhere, the problem is just in the JSX compiler). npm -v react-tools says 2.7.0

Comment: I would reinstall react-tools, as again, it works for me. my jsx version is 0.12.1

Comment: I looked into the package JSON in the react-tools module, apparently it's 0.12.2. Another weird thing is that I tried the same code a different machine and it worked. I checked the react-tools version on that machine and it's also 0.12.2. I'm completely confused.

Comment: might be some configuration clash or something, it's hard to say as there are no errors... here similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887291/react-tool-jsx-compile-a-not-working-script

Comment: It's not possible to make the output from jsx more verbose, is it?

Comment: Try embedding jsx code in parenthesis and using semicolon. ex: `return (<div>Text</div>);`

Comment: That, unfortunately, doesn't help either.

Comment: try `jsx src/ build/` instead of `jsx /src /build`

Comment: Name your file `helloworld.jsx.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to wrap your html in brackets.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({displayName: "Hello",
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Hello, {this.props.name}</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but i've written a jsx to javascript compiler using gulp using browserify and reactify
it runs on the background

https://github.com/jedt/basic-react-boilerplate

(PS. I've tested your jsx and it works for me.)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs i've seen that the default output stream for jsx is stdout, which means it should output the file into the console.
Either try to use the --output option or redirect the command into a file:

```
jsx ./src/helloworld.jsx --output ./build/helloworld.js
```

or

```
jsx ./src/helloworld.jsx > ./build/helloworld.js
```

I myself couldn't run your code with jsx (It said my syntax isn't good?), maybe try to use babel-cli instead:
[How to convert react JSX files to simple JavaScript file [offline transformation]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456182/how-to-convert-react-jsx-files-to-simple-javascript-file-offline-transformation/34456277#34456277)