# How to convert react JSX files to simple JavaScript file [offline transformation]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react.js. Just started learning it. So my question may seems to be stupid but please answer it.

I have created a simple .js file with following code:

```
var Hello=React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<h1>Hello World</h1>);
    }
});
```

It is in JSX syntax and to convert it to simple JavaScript file I used following command:

```
babel --preset react JSX_Files --watch --out-dir public/javascripts
```

Here *JSX_Files* is my source folder and *public/javascripts* is the folder where I want my transformed .js files.

But I'm getting following error while transformation:

```
SyntaxError: JSX_Files/example.js: Unexpected token (3:16)
  1 | var Hello=React.createClass({
  2 |     render: function(){
> 3 |         return (<h1>Hello World</h1>);
    |                 ^
  4 |     }
  5 | });
```

But when I use Babel REPL (http://babeljs.io/repl/) , it converts it without any error.

Now please tell me where I'm doing wrong. Why I'm getting syntax error while offline transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using babel-cli you need to use a plugin to transform jsx syntax to js syntax that the browser understands.
See the following link:
http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/
You'll need to install babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx plugin and use it in a .babelrc file like that:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

Then your babel command should work.

Comment: thanks.. Actually I didn't created .babelrc file. Now after creating this file command is executing without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Try `babel --presets react JSX_Files --watch --out-dir public/javascripts` (s on the end of preset).

Comment: Have you run `npm install babel-preset-react` ?

Comment: Yes I did that. I was getting error because I haven't created .babelrc file. But now its working. thanks for your answer.